# method queue delegate comparisons

Tags: c#, delegates

I have a Queue that holds a list of delegates that correspond to methods that I want to run in the future. I would like to only have singular instances of any particular method/parameter in queue. In other words, a queue of DoOne(), DoTwo(2), DoThree(3) should be possible where as a queue of DoOne(), DoTwo(2), DoTwo(2) should not be allowed.

I have noticed that _queue.Contains(Func< int >) works through the minimal testing that I have done, but I am worried if I am missing something. Is this a sufficient enough test to determine whether a particular method/parameter is queued, to satisfy what I am trying to accomplish?

```
Queue<Func<int>> _queue = new Queue<Func<int>>();

void Queue(Func<int> Method)
{
    if (!_queue.Contains(Method))
    _queue.Enqueue(Method);
}

void QueueOne()
{
    Queue( () => DoOne() );
}

void QueueTwo(int val)
{
    Queue( () => DoTwo(val) );
}

void DoOne()
{
    return 1;
}

void DoTwo(int val)
{
    return val;
}
```

Comment: Is the number of delegate types known, or should this handle an arbitrary N number of delegates?

Answer (score 1):

Since each time you call QueueOne or QueueTwo, you create a new function that is passed to the Queue function, I have my doubts that you can find a way to compare those to each other and determine that they match.

This leads me to recommend that you pass an identifier that you will use to make the uniqueness comparison.

In my sample code below, I chose to do this using the CallerMemberName to identify the name of the calling function (i.e. "QueueOne" or "QueueTwo") and refuse to enqueue the item if the queue still had a matching entry.

```
Queue<Tuple<string, Func<int>>> _queue = new Queue<Tuple<string, Func<int>>>();

void Queue(Func<int> method, [CallerMemberName] string caller = null)
{
    if (!_queue.Any(v => v.Item1 == caller))
        _queue.Enqueue(Tuple.Create(caller, method));
}

void QueueOne()
{
    Queue(() => DoOne());
}

void QueueTwo(int val)
{
    Queue(() => DoTwo(val));
}

int DoOne()
{
    return 1;
}

int DoTwo(int val)
{
    return val;
}
```

Comment: I had my doubts as well but if you test the code, and queue up DoOne twice you will actually see that it will reject on the second pass correctly. Not sure if it was a fluke, or standard behavior.

In any case, something like this was actually what I envisioned the fallback solution to look like. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are calling with a parameter they are treated different objects (see Closures in c#)

Change your logicto check the duplication to:

**if (!_queue.Where(x => x.Method == Method.Method).Any())
                _queue.Enqueue(m);**

this will help you to stop adding same method again (even if they have diff parameters)

Comment: And if you declare 2 identical funcs, () => 1, you're telling me that the call to `.Method` gives you the same result in both cases? I think not.

Comment: you are wrong..give it a try before commenting blindly. take the code from above question and try my solution before misleading others based on you assumptions

Comment: Actually I seemed to have omitted the fact that a method/parameter combo is used to determine uniqueness, not just the method. I have updated my post